# How to understand TensorFlow source code for Imagenet preprocessing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet, imagenet

I want to understand and replicate how does tensorflow.keras do the preprocessing of imagenet in the function [tf.keras.applications.resnet.preprocess_input](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/resnet/preprocess_input?version=stable), but I can not understand the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py):

```py
@keras_export('keras.applications.imagenet_utils.preprocess_input')
@keras_modules_injection
def preprocess_input(*args, **kwargs):
  return imagenet_utils.preprocess_input(*args, **kwargs)
```

The definition seems to be recursive. Moreover, the documentation does not say anything about the function. How can I see what is this function really doing?

Comment: In the past, I saw it in the source code, maybe if you look for older keras versions. Here there seems to be old version documentations. Try to find something like 2.1.0 or 2.2.0 (or values near these): http://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.0.8/layers/convolutional/#convolution2d. The idea was that each model had its own preprocessing, but the VGG used a centering of each channel. So it was, with an image input from 0 to 255: channel green gets its value minus something around 255/2 (but not exactly). Each other channel followed the same process, with different means.

Comment: I know they do mean subtraction and scaling, but I want to know also how do they do the crops.

Comment: No crops in preprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this link will help. https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py. The definition is actually not recursive because the import statement `from keras_applications import imagenet_utils` will allow you to use the preprocess_input function from the imagenet_utils located in keras rather than calling itself.